# Any performance or memory difference between setting input value in ngOnInit vs input set property in angular .ts file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there any real advantages between doing something like this

```js
_user: any;

@Input()
public set user(user: any) {
  this._user = user;
}
```

vs doing something like this

```js
@Input() user: User;
_user: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this._user = this.user;
}
```

when I pass the object to my child component like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <app-child [user]="user"></app-child>
</div>
```

Comment: The two versions are not functionally equivalent, so comparing performance/memory is a bit of a moot point to me. One can only catch the correct value if it is immediately set to the final value and never changes, the other one will update if the input changes.

Comment: Ok, please tell me which one is more appropriate for saving and using the values for 'user'? Ex. this component is a bootstrap card and I'm passing in the user data to the card so that if the user clicks on the card, it takes them to the profile page. So I need the 'id' of the 'user'

Comment: `@Input() user: any` already is a member that you can use. You don't need to assign the value to a second variable.

Comment: What you suggest is where I had a problem! In the component (bootstrap card) I have a method called from a click event to "Like" the "user" and on the subscribe callback that gets returned from my controller I want to access "user" to show a message on screen with the user property 'userName' but "user" is empty. The callback .subscribe(result => ...) won't have the user data

Comment: You should open a new question with your actual question and all the required code to demonstrate and replicate the issue. We won't get far by guessing things in comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable `user` is not private when you are using:

```
@Input() user: User;
```

You don't need to reassign to another variable.
`@Input` accessor for field is much simpler to use. But if you want some logic while accessing variable or you want that variable to be private you should use `@Input` accessor for setters/getters. I.E.:

```
private _user: User;

@Input
set user(u: User) {
    u.name = 'Foo'
    this._user = u;
}
```

So it's pretty same for performance. More information you can find [there](https://medium.com/@bharat.tiwari/intercept-input-property-change-in-angular-690567eb63ec)